# I want to show cateogory wise product

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make an e-commerce project for that reason I want to show category wise product, but I am really confused have no faith in me that I will able to do that so I need some guide or help for this

I just created a view:

```
cart = request.session.get('cart')

        if not cart:
            request.session['cart'] = {}



        #products = None
        cats = Category.get_categories()
        brands = Brand.get_brands()
        sliders = Slider.objects.all()
        offers = Offer.objects.all()

        categoryID = request.GET.get('category')
        brandID = request.GET.get('brand')

        if categoryID:
            products = Product.get_products_by_category(categoryID)
        else:
            products = Product.get_all_products()

        if brandID:
            proucts = Product.get_brands_by_products(brandID)
        else:
            products = Product.get_all_products()


        products = []
        catprods = Product.objects.values('category', 'id')
        cats = {item['category'] for item in catprods}
        for cat in cats:
            product = Product.objects.filter(category=cat)

            products.append(['products'])
        args = {
        'products':products,
        'cats': cats,
        'brands': brands,
        'sliders':sliders,
        'offers':offers
        }
        return render(request, 'Home/index.html', args)
```

Here is my index where I want to show category wise product

```
{%for product in products%}
        <div class="card-2">
            <div class="card">
                
                  <div class="picture">
                    <a href="{% url 'product_details' product.id %}">
                    <img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="" style="width: 170px;
                        height: 180px;">
                      </a>
                </div>
                <div class="amount">
                    <p class="P">{{product.price}}</p>
                    <p class="n">{{product.name}}</p>

                    {% if request.session.customer %}
              <form action="/#{{product.id}}" method="POST" class="btn-block">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <input hidden type="text" name='product' value='{{product.id}}'>
                      <input type="submit" class="float-right btn btn-light  form-control"
                      value="Add To Cart">
            </form>
            {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}"><small class="badge badge-info">Please Login First</small></a>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            {%endfor%}
```

Its giving me an error. don't know what to do please help

Comment: Please provide the error message, this would be helpful.

Comment: No reverse found at product_details this is the error showing but whenever I remove products.append(['products']) this line the error gets vanished

Comment: man, you first get products by category then taken queryset rewrtite when get product by brand, I think you need use Q or 'filter" api for model.objects
and what you mean in this string? products.append(['products'])

Comment: can you show me a sample @Mykyta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
        products = Product.get_all_products()
        cats = Category.get_categories()
        brands = Brand.get_brands()
        sliders = Slider.objects.all()
        offers = Offer.objects.all()

        categoryID = request.GET.get('category')
        brandID = request.GET.get('brand')

        if categoryID: #here you filter category by categoryID from request
            products = products.filter(category__id=categoryID)

        if brandID: #here you filter brand by brandID from request
            products = Product.filter(brand__id=brandID)

        #catprods = Product.objects.values('category', 'id')
        #cats = {item['category'] for item in catprods}
        #for cat in cats:
        #    product = Product.objects.filter(category=cat)
        #    products.append(['products'])
        # code above doesn't need I think, here you just get objects with 2 field, but your products queryset has already filtered
        args = {
        'products':products,
        'cats': cats,
        'brands': brands,
        'sliders':sliders,
        'offers':offers
        }
        return render(request, 'Home/index.html', args)
```

Comment: of course we filtered products by chosen category, if you want right this

Comment: but its not showing bro @Mykyta its just showing all products I have added the index.html file where I want to show please check